Can't install library with vcpkg using MinGW compiler
I'm trying to install the tbb library on Windows using the MinGW C++ compiler g++ and the vcpkg package manager. However, running .\vcpkg install tbb --triplet=x64-mingw-static --host-triplet=x64-mingw-static gives the following error:
The C++ compiler "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue?

GitHub Bug Report: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/40664

The output of .\vcpkg --version in C:\Users\<user>\vcpkg is:
vcpkg package management program version 2024-08-01-fd884a0d390d12783076341bd43d77c3a6a15658

See LICENSE.txt for license information.

The output of .\g++ --version in C:\msys64\mingw64\bin is:
g++ (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 14.1.0
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

The output of .\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe --version in C:\msys64\mingw64\bin is:
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 14.1.0
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

The output of .\vcpkg install tbb --triplet=x64-mingw-static --host-triplet=x64-mingw-static in C:\Users\<user>\vcpkg is:
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    tbb:x64-mingw-static@2021.13.0
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-mingw-static...
Compiler found: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
Restored 0 package(s) from C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 226 us. Use --debug to see more details.
Installing 1/1 tbb:x64-mingw-static@2021.13.0...
Building tbb:x64-mingw-static@2021.13.0...
C:\Users\<user>\vcpkg\triplets\community\x64-mingw-static.cmake: info: loaded community triplet from here. Community triplets are not built in the curated registry and are thus less likely to succeed.
-- Using cached oneapi-src-oneTBB-v2021.13.0.tar.gz.
-- Cleaning sources at C:/Users/<user>/vcpkg/buildtrees/tbb/src/v2021.13.0-c5ed208c36.clean. Use --editable to skip cleaning for the packages you specify.
-- Extracting source C:/Users/<user>/vcpkg/downloads/oneapi-src-oneTBB-v2021.13.0.tar.gz
-- Using source at C:/Users/<user>/vcpkg/buildtrees/tbb/src/v2021.13.0-c5ed208c36.clean
-- Configuring x64-mingw-static
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:127 (message):
    Command failed: C:/Users/<user>/vcpkg/downloads/tools/ninja/1.10.2-windows/ninja.exe -v
    Working Directory: C:/Users/<user>/vcpkg/buildtrees/tbb/x64-mingw-static-rel/vcpkg-parallel-configure
    Error code: 1
    See logs for more information:
      C:\Users\<user>\vcpkg\buildtrees\tbb\config-x64-mingw-static-dbg-CMakeCache.txt.log
      C:\Users\<user>\vcpkg\buildtrees\tbb\config-x64-mingw-static-rel-CMakeCache.txt.log
      C:\Users\<user>\vcpkg\buildtrees\tbb\config-x64-mingw-static-dbg-CMakeConfigureLog.yaml.log
      C:\Users\<user>\vcpkg\buildtrees\tbb\config-x64-mingw-static-rel-CMakeConfigureLog.yaml.log
      C:\Users\<user>\vcpkg\buildtrees\tbb\config-x64-mingw-static-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  installed/x64-mingw-static/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_configure.cmake:269 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  ports/tbb/portfile.cmake:17 (vcpkg_cmake_configure)
  scripts/ports.cmake:192 (include)


error: building tbb:x64-mingw-static failed with: BUILD_FAILED
See https://learn.microsoft.com/vcpkg/troubleshoot/build-failures?WT.mc_id=vcpkg_inproduct_cli for more information.
Elapsed time to handle tbb:x64-mingw-static: 6.3 s
Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+tbb
You can submit a new issue at:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?title=[tbb]+Build+error+on+x64-mingw-static&body=Copy+issue+body+from+C%3A%2FUsers%2F<user>%2Fvcpkg%2Finstalled%2Fvcpkg%2Fissue_body.md

Here are the log files:



File
PasteBin Link




C:/Users/<user>/vcpkg/installed/vcpkg/issue_body.md
https://pastebin.com/KGhPaR1r


C:\Users\<user>\vcpkg\buildtrees\tbb\config-x64-mingw-static-rel-CMakeConfigureLog.yaml.log
https://pastebin.com/CM3kysi8


C:\Users\<user>\vcpkg\buildtrees\tbb\config-x64-mingw-static-rel-CMakeCache.txt.log
https://pastebin.com/bkJkstb2


C:\Users\<user>\vcpkg\buildtrees\tbb\config-x64-mingw-static-out.log
https://pastebin.com/GkbrQwYs


C:\Users\<user>\vcpkg\buildtrees\tbb\config-x64-mingw-static-dbg-CMakeConfigureLog.yaml.log
https://pastebin.com/UZDx7Wnt


C:\Users\<user>\vcpkg\buildtrees\tbb\config-x64-mingw-static-dbg-CMakeCache.txt.log
https://pastebin.com/qgDL3vJc



The relevant part of C:\Users\<user>\vcpkg\buildtrees\tbb\config-x64-mingw-static-out.log appears to be the following:
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 14.1.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:73 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: 'C:/Users/<user>/vcpkg/buildtrees/tbb/x64-mingw-static-rel/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-cvmmjb'
    
    Run Build Command(s): C:/Users/<user>/vcpkg/downloads/tools/ninja/1.10.2-windows/ninja.exe -v cmTC_ef730
    [1/2] C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_ef730.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -c C:/Users/<user>/vcpkg/buildtrees/tbb/x64-mingw-static-rel/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-cvmmjb/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    [2/2] C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe   CMakeFiles/cmTC_ef730.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -o cmTC_ef730.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_ef730.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
    FAILED: cmTC_ef730.exe 
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe   CMakeFiles/cmTC_ef730.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -o cmTC_ef730.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_ef730.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
    Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

The main error seems to be
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.

which literally translates to
The system cannot find the path specified.

However, I don't know which path this is referring to. As shown above, the file C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe does exist.

Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden. is the error. Is the compiler path correct? Please post all relevant information within the question without relying on external links

@AlanBirtles Thanks for your comment. I have added the relevant part of the log to the post. As you said, the relevant error seems to be The system cannot find the path specified.. As far as I understand, this is not referring to the compiler path, since as shown above the compiler does exist at that location. I don't understand which other file this could be referring to.

I was able to resolve the question by deleting the following registry entries:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

The following questions seem to be related:

The system cannot find the path specified
[BUG] It is not able to compile a simple test program.
CMake does not accept MinGW compilers
Cmake with MinGW fails compile test
Android Studio Cmake: "The C compiler clang.exe is not able to compile a simple test program
CMake building for Windows (clang-cl) using Ninja Generator
MinGW Make throwing "The system cannot find the path specified." error

